Failed to determine the health of the cluster. , with exit code 69
I am trying to create an Enrollment code for my Elasticsearch using
bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s node 

and i am getting this error and i cant find a solution for it. I followed the instructions from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.13/targz.html.
Does it have to do something with the password that i set using
export ELASTIC_PASSWORD="your_password"


The reason may be various. I will share some information that may help.

bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token command uses localhost
as default. adding --url can help you to fix it.

Here are some steps for debugging:

curl -ks "https://localhost:9200" -u elastic:your_password
bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s node --url "https://node_ip:9200"
check http.host in cat grep -v ^# elasticsearch.yml and make sure it's set to 0.0.0.0


Check the Health API
curl -u elastic:your_password http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty

